# How to convert IP Address to Country Name

Tags: google-sheets, jotform

URl - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lvmwHqINzKxjKgZjmDAkntFDo2R_lrfy2GUd-ohCA2A/edit#gid=1237083423

As you can see there is a column which displays IP Address.
Basically it is a survey form (JotForm) whose responses are real-time updated on Google spreadsheets.

Based on IP Address available, how can I find its respective country name.

I got one solution

```
=query( importhtml("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & G4, "table", 2), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Country:' ", 0 )
```

But in this I am facing one issue. I am using jotforms and integrating it with Google Spreadsheets. It gives me location of all responses received till date. I used drag down feature and dragged it to cell no 100. As as soon the new response is received, the information is now stored at cell no 101 and all the other where I have entered formula are left blank.

Any workaround for this? Will any array formula will do?

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @N8sBug This is where I am stuck.. A small help from you will be really helpful. Thanks for your help till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems to be working well.  Unfortunately, I have not found an easier way for this using arrayformula().  But your question regarding how to make this update auto-magically is very doable.  The following will assume you have placed your formula in cell G2.  (You might find that you will want to use this in other places too, in which case you will just create different functions to make it work and put them in onChange()).

1. Open up your script editor.  Tools->Script Editor
2. Add the following code to the end of the script editor:

   ```
   function updateCountry(){
     var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = mysheet.getSheetByName("Submissions");  //Sheet Name is "Submissions"
     var sourceCell = sheet.getRange(2,7,1,1); //Row 2, Column G, First Row in G, 1      Column in Range
     var targetRows = sheet.getRange(3,7,sheet.getLastRow()-2, 1); //Row 3, Column G, Last row currently populated, 1 Column in Range
     sourceCell.copyTo(targetRows); //Will copy the formula from sourceCell to targetRows.

   }

   function onChange(){
     updateCountry(); //Run this on every change.
   }
   ```
3. Save the edited script file as "CCI Responses".
4. Now inside the script editor go to Resources->Current Projects Triggers. Use the pull downs to produce the following settings and save: [image: Triggers]
5. Now see what happens when a new IP is added to column G.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you tell me how to find out no. of positive responses for q1 in month of June for India. I wrote this but ain't working =sumproduct(arrayformula(if(right(left("Sheet1"!A$2:A,5),2)="05",1,0)),arrayformula(if("Sheet1"!B$2:B="Positive",1,0)),arrayformula(if("Sheet1"!G$2:G="India",1,0)))

Comment: @chiragvora  You might want to look over your date format in Sheet1 column A.  If you look at the data in the cell editor box, versus what is displayed in the sheet you will see a difference when you scroll through.  Also recall that the cell parsing (ie right(left(Sheet1!A$2:A,5),2)) we went through was used to deal with the fact that the original problem had your date format as:  dd/mm/yyyy.  I also think you need to remove "" from the sheet name.  Furthermore, if you are using the newer version of google spreadsheet, you *might* have to use countifs as I described in your previous question.

Comment: This is what I have written 
=COUNTIFS(arrayformula(if(right(left(Sheet1!A$2:A,6),2)="6",1,0)),if(Sheet1!B$2:B="Positive",1,0),if(Sheet1!G$2:G="India",1,0))
Error - COUNTIFS expects all arguments after position 2 to be in pairs.
URL - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lvmwHqINzKxjKgZjmDAkntFDo2R_lrfy2GUd-ohCA2A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try something like this... =countifs(arrayformula(left(Sheet1!A$2:A,1)),"=6",Sheet1!B$2:B,"=Positive",Sheet1!G$2:G,"=India")

Comment: Note that the formula in the arrayformula has changed because the data in column A is not consistently formatted and is not in the format you originally had.  I recommend taking a column out of the way, and playing with =arrayformula(right(left(Sheet1A$2:A,5,2))) to see what I mean.  The cell parsing is thrown off by the new data format.

Comment: This is what it is coming
Error: Formula parse error.

Comment: I think so there is some error in that sheet even after formatting the dates are not getting formatted. So see this URL - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Db54eQ2CG6qBUNxqt6tbN_-6OdBVrc6rJ15FnL9KYMA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see your formula.  You are missing the "!" inbetween Sheet1 and A$2.  I'm trying to chat with you while you are working, but you are not responding.  Email me to continue this, we are not supposed to be chatting away on SO.

Comment: I am not able to chat with you as it is coming "No User online to chat with". Can you come again or can u give me ur email address so that I can give u access. Already there is ! inbetween but still there is error. I have temporarily given edit to anyone..

Comment: I don't know your email address